# UIImageView & video memory

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, video-memory

I have interesting problem with my UiimageViews.
I have an application (game with 2 houses) where I loaded a lot of images on the screen (I'm using UIIMageView).
Works fine on ios4.3 but have a lot crashes on ios5 (I've look at free memory on spc programs difference is around 40-50mb!).

I've removed all @2x images (for retina devices) where it was possible and now i have somewhat less crashes - but they still present.

I've analyzed and found that all crashes appear between **viewWillAppear** and **viewDidAppear**.
Looks like when images loading into video memory.

I have 2 houses in game and I can loading any house first, then I unload house (of course instruments shows that I have no leaks). I try to load second house and then I have crash.
Looks like Images not unloading from videomemory. **Is it possible ?**

When we remove @2x images then we can load more houses but then crash again sometimes between viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typical case of your app being terminated because it takes up too much memory. You can check this by implementing the didReceiveMemoryWarning callback. How big are your images? There are a number of posts on memory issues with UIImageViews, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994914/unload-image-of-uiimageview-thats-offscreen). You must make sure that the UImageViews are removed from their superviews and properly released when not needed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. Of course we have MEMORY WARNING in console. But we wont remove any views when loading it...\

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a memory problem to me... Do you re-use removed objects? What is your console output when the app crashes?